# React Smooth Skew Scrolling ref height Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, smooth-scrolling, portfolio

I am trying to add a smooth scroll or aka 'lag scroll' to my React app. Everything seems to be working perfectly as the scroll is now slowed down. The issue that I am having is that the 'scrollContainer' ref's height is changing on refresh. When I console log *scrollingContainerRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().height*, on initial load the height is 5278.7...., then when the page is refreshed the height changes and remains at 4956.7.... on each refresh. This then causes the footer to be cut off. I attached both the useWindowSize.js custom hook and smoothScroll.js component to this thread. Please let me know what else you need to try and debug this issue. I also attached screen shots of the console showing the different heights. For an example of the smooth scroll that I am trying to implement please check out this person's portfolio https://jesperlandberg.dev/.

-Thank you,
[console log height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFb2w.png) [console log height(2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6nS6.png)

```js
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import useWindowSize from "./useWindowSize";

const SmoothScroll = ({ children }) => {
  // 1.
  const windowSize = useWindowSize();

  //2.
  const scrollingContainerRef = useRef();

  // 3.
  const data = {
    ease: 0.1,
    current: 0,
    previous: 0,
    rounded: 0,
  };

  // 4.
  useEffect(() => {
    setBodyHeight();
    console.log(windowSize.height);
    console.log(scrollingContainerRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().height)
  }, [windowSize.height]);

  const setBodyHeight = () => {
    document.body.style.height = `${
      scrollingContainerRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().height
    }px`;
  };

  // 5.
  useEffect(() => {
    requestAnimationFrame(() => smoothScrollingHandler());
  }, []);

  const smoothScrollingHandler = () => {
    data.current = window.scrollY;
    data.previous += (data.current - data.previous) * data.ease;
    data.rounded = Math.round(data.previous * 100) / 100;

    scrollingContainerRef.current.style.transform = `translateY(-${data.previous}px)`;

    // Recursive call
    requestAnimationFrame(() => smoothScrollingHandler());
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div ref={scrollingContainerRef}>{children}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SmoothScroll;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function useWindowSize() {
  function getSize() {
    return {
      width: window.innerWidth,
      height: window.innerHeight,
    };
  }

  const [windowSize, setWindowSize] = useState(getSize);

  useEffect(() => {
    function handleResize() {
      setWindowSize(getSize());
    }

    window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", handleResize);
  }, []);

  return windowSize;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```